# Wordpress - Heroku Issues

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I have been trying to get WordPress to work on Heroku for a couple of days now and I can't seem to get it to work no matter what, as after some normal functioning (adding pages, messing with the ElemntorDB, adding plugins through GitHub push & commits, etc.) the Project holding my Wordpress just crashes out of nowhere and reverts back to the initial Wordpress installation page:

[image]

I have tried:

- Adjusting the "Site Permalinks" and "Website URL" settings to make sure that everything is working properly,
- Using the "Hobby" Heroku Dyno to make sure it wasn't a "free-tier" issue, and it is not being lost somewhere in the ephemeral Dyno structure,
- Making sure that the ClearDB & the AWS Bucket are correctly connected,

But no success :( Has anyone managed to work on a Wordpress Heroku Instance from start-to-end without it crashing and having to wait 30 min for some reason to continue work?

Comment: My guess: `wp-config.php` is getting wiped out when you deploy (and on the daily dyno restart). You likely need to create this locally, add it to the repo, and include it in deployments; WordPress assumes a persistent filesystem in several spots like this, IIRC.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hmm... I doubt it. I have created and using my own "WordPress-Heroku Template", could you maybe clone it and see if you get the same issue as I do. https://github.com/migbash-websites/wordpress-heroku-template